# Determining Type and Bandwidth of a filter

Tags: image-processing, filters, 2d

Given a filter, if it is given as an equation such as:

$$f(x,y) = \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\right) \exp\left(-\frac{x^2 + y^2}{\sigma^2}\right)$$

Or in a kernel such as:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -4 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
How much can I find out about the filter. Specifically can I find out if it is a highpass/ lowpass/ bandpass filter (if so how?), and can I find out the bandwidth of the filter?

If it helps, the context is image processing.

Thanks

Comment: To filter an image using a kernel, you use convolution, so the kernel is a sort of impulse response function.  To see the frequency response of a filter, you perform an FFT of the impulse response.  In this case, your kernel is only 3x3, so I think you would pad it with zeros first to see a higher-resolution response spectrum.  Then you can look at/measure the spectrum to see the type and bandwidth, etc.

Answer (score 6):

As others have mentioned, performing a 2D FFT on the kernel will give you the frequency response of the filter. However, it's worth mentioning that 2D filters can be analyzed using the [Z-transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform), which may or may not provide deeper insight, depending on the filter (and what you want to know).

For example, given the kernel you specified, the corresponding [difference equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_equation) would be

$$y(n_1,n_2) = x(n_1+1,n_2) + x(n_1,n_2 + 1) + x(n_1-1,n_2) + x(n_1,n_2-1) - 4x(n_1,n_2).$$

Its Z-transform is

$$ Y(z_1,z_2) = z_1X(z_1,z_2) + z_2X(z_1,z_2) + z^{-1}_1X(z_1,z_2) + z_2^{-1}X(z_1,z_2) - 4X(z_1,z_2),$$

which, after rearranging, yields the following [transfer function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_function) for the filter:

$$ H(z_1,z_2) = \frac{Y(z_1,z_2)}{X(z_1,z_2)} = z_1 + z_2 + z_1^{-1} + z_2^{-1} - 4.$$

To determine the magnitude response, just plug in a pair of [complex exponentials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_exponential) and simplify, as follows:

$$ \begin{aligned} 
H(e^{iw_1},e^{iw_2}) & = e^{iw_1} + e^{iw_2} + e^{-iw_1} + e^{-iw_2} - 4  \\ 
                     & = (e^{iw_1} + e^{-iw_1}) + (e^{iw_2} + e^{-iw_2}) - 4 \\
                     & = 2\cos{w_1} + 2\cos{w_2} - 4 \\
|H(e^{iw_1},e^{iw_2})| & = 2\sqrt{ (\cos{w_1} + \cos{w_2} - 2)^2  } .
\end{aligned} 
$$

Evaluating the magnitude response at extreme frequencies will give you a sense of highpass vs. lowpass for the filter. For example,

$$ |H(e^{i0},e^{i0})| = 2\sqrt{(\cos{0} + \cos{0} - 2)^2} = 2\sqrt{(1+1-2)^2} = 0,$$
and
$$ |H(e^{i\pi},e^{i\pi})| = 2\sqrt{(\cos{\pi} + \cos{\pi} - 2)^2} = 2\sqrt{(-1-1-2)^2} = 8.$$

Of course, the transfer function can be evaluated directly to plot the magnitude response of the filter as well. Here's an example using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

def H(z1,z2):
    return z1 + z2 + 1./z1 + 1./z2 - 4.0

n = 100
w1 = w2 = np.linspace(-np.pi,np.pi, n)    
mag = np.zeros((n,n))

for i1 in xrange(0,n):
    for i2 in xrange(0,n):
        z1 = np.exp(1j*w1[i1])
        z2 = np.exp(1j*w2[i2])
        mag[i1,i2] = np.abs(H(z1,z2))

fig = py.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')    
X, Y = np.meshgrid(w1,w2)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, mag, cmap='bone', alpha=.5)
py.show()
```

[image: Filter magnitude response]

Keep in mind that if you use the kernel 2D FFT technique, the resulting magnitudes won't necessarily be centered at zero like the above plot.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the MATLAB Image Processing Toolbox, you could use freqz2:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/freqz2.html

Scipy code for a 2-d DFT/FFT as noted by @endolith and @Mohammad

```
h = array([[0,1,0],[1,-4,1],[0,1,0]])
N=32; 
figure(); 
imshow(abs(fft2(h,s=(N,N))),interpolation='nearest');
colorbar()
```

Answer (score 3):

The negative of the second derivative of a gaussian kernel as you have described it turns out to be what is called the ['Mexican Hat'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_hat_wavelet). kernel. You can see some of its uses in the wiki.

As it stands, such a filter can be used to detect edges. The kernel you have provided can also be used in the same capacity.

The best way to be able to tell if a filter is low/band/high pass is to observe it in the frequency domain, as that will tell you what bands are being suppressed, or left alone. Performing the 2-dimensional DFT, and taking the magnitude of the result should give you this information.